# How can I change specific elements in all samples of a .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

As input, I have a .csv file like:

```
user, withdraw, date
50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8, -125, 01-02-2015
674BCF0CD236621E5680073334A73C32, -5, 01-02-2015
E17E1691D35FB2FB675E3B787B8BEDF1, -845, 01-02-2015
50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8, -250, 01-02-2015
674BCF0CD236621E5680073334A73C32, -98, 01-02-2015
50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8, -17, 01-02-2015
```

I would like to identify all similar 'hash' codes and change them for labels such as 'user1', 'user2', 'user3'...and so on.

I have been trying to do that without success with **pandas**. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: I don't believe you can update. Instead, read, modify, and replace. ://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html 
and  https ://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020858/inline-csv-file-editing-with-python

Comment: Thanks for the support @DavyM, I have no clue why people down voted it. Anyhow, answering your question, I would like to change the .csv, or to generate a new one.

Comment: Seriously, any clue why people just hated my post? =/. I really would like to know what I did wrong. Also, should I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first read CSV into Pandas DF:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

yields:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
                               user  withdraw        date
0  50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8      -125  01-02-2015
1  674BCF0CD236621E5680073334A73C32        -5  01-02-2015
2  E17E1691D35FB2FB675E3B787B8BEDF1      -845  01-02-2015
3  50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8      -250  01-02-2015
4  674BCF0CD236621E5680073334A73C32       -98  01-02-2015
5  50D8BF0DA22D6C914777D8F59DAAB4D8       -17  01-02-2015
```

now we can factorize `user` column:

```
In [85]: df['user'] = 'user' + pd.Series((pd.factorize(df.user)[0]+1).astype(str))

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
    user  withdraw        date
0  user1      -125  01-02-2015
1  user2        -5  01-02-2015
2  user3      -845  01-02-2015
3  user1      -250  01-02-2015
4  user2       -98  01-02-2015
5  user1       -17  01-02-2015
```

and write DF back to csv:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/file_new.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works beautifully.

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first build a dictionary of users as follows:

```
import csv

hashes = {}
user_number = 1
entries = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        user = row[0]

        if user not in hashes:
            hashes[user] = "user{}".format(user_number)
            user_number += 1

        row[0] = hashes[user]
        entries.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    csv_output.writerows(entries)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` containing:

```
user,withdraw,date
user1,-125,01-02-2015
user2,-5,01-02-2015
user3,-845,01-02-2015
user1,-250,01-02-2015
user2,-98,01-02-2015
user1,-17,01-02-2015
```